Subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies trichotomy and multiplicative closure but not additive closure

Is it possible to construct a subset $\mathbb{P}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that
satisfies trichotomy and multiplicative closure but not additive closure?

Trichotomy says that if $x\in\mathbb{R},$ then exactly one of the following holds-
$$x\in\mathbb{P}$$
$$-x\in\mathbb{P}$$
$$x=0$$
Multiplicative closure says that if $x,y\in\mathbb{P},$ then $xy\in\mathbb{P}.$
I think it is not possible to construct such a set. I feel that any set satisfying these two properties must be exactly the set of positive reals (hence the suggestive notation).
Let $S$ be the set of all positive reals.
Suppose $x\in S.$ We want to show $x\in\mathbb{P}.$ We know that $\sqrt{x}\in\mathbb{R}.$
By trichotomy, either $\sqrt{x}=0,$ or $-\sqrt{x}\in\mathbb{P},$ or $\sqrt{x}\in\mathbb{P}.$
The first case isn't possible as that would give $x=0.$ The other two cases imply $x\in\mathbb{P}$ by multiplicative closure. Hence, $S\subseteq\mathbb{P}.$ Note that $\mathbb{P}$ can't contain anything else due to trichotomy.
Hence, $S=\mathbb{P}.$
Motivation for this question:

I am interested in knowing if multiplicative closure and trichotomy
are strong enough to uniquely define the set of positive reals.

Most definitions also assume additive closure, but I feel it's not needed.

+1 for interesting question.

The rationals satisfy multiplicative closure and trichotomy so that can't be sufficient to define the positive reals.

Actually , the rationals satisfy additive closure too , @CyclotomicField , hence that too is insufficient. We might require limit closure.

@CyclotomicField, the rationals do not satisfy trichotomy. $1$ and $-1$ are both rationals.

If $\mathbb P \subset \mathbb R - \{0\}$ is a subset that is closed under multiplication and that satisfies the trichotomy law in $\mathbb R$ then $\mathbb P$ contains every positive number $t>0$, because either $\sqrt{t}$ or $-\sqrt{t}$ is in $\mathbb P$ but $t = (\sqrt{t})^2=(-\sqrt{t})^2$.
Applying the trichotomy law again it follows that $\mathbb P$ contains no negative number.
So $\mathbb P$ is exactly the set of positive numbers, as you thought.

Does your $P$ have Additive Closure ? I am not sure this is what OP wants. In case Additive Closure is not actually necessary , then why should most authors & most textbooks use that Criterion ?

@Prem Lee, like the OP, is assuming only trichotomy and multiplicative closure.  This is enough to prove that $\mathbb P$ consists of the positives, and is thus additively closed.  Additive closure (along with some other properties) is used in real analysis textbooks because those textbooks are defining the tuple $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot, \mathbb P)$; here we're treating $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot)$ as given and characterizing $\mathbb P$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Agreed , thank you for high-lighting that , @RaviFernando , OP Question will still remain : In the "Axiomatic treatment" where $P$ is specified using Additive Closure : Is that Additive Closure really necessary or just a convenient short-cut ?

@Prem If one is trying to define the ordered field $\mathbb R$ (as opposed to taking $(\mathbb R, +, \cdot)$ as given, which I believe was the OP's intent), then I would guess that additive closure is necessary.  I don't have a counterexample though.  It might be interesting to ask as a separate question, if it hasn't been asked before.

Going by OP title , we can take $(-1,+1)$ as a Subset of $R$ with multiplicative closure & trichotomy with $[0,+1)$ as the Positive Subset of that retaining multiplicative closure & trichotomy , @RaviFernando , Will that be a Counter-Example ?

No, that's not a counterexample, because trichotomy is quantified over every real number: $\forall x \in \mathbb R$, either $x \in \mathbb P$ or $-x \in \mathbb P$ or $x=0$.

And I second the interest of that "second question" @RaviFernando.

OP wants "Subset of $R$ that satisfies trichotomy and multiplicative closure but not additive closure"
Additive Closure is necessary.
Without that , we can make Degenerate $P$ which will mot match the commonly known Positives.
Example 1 :
That (Degenerate) Subset $P$ is this :
$P = \{ +1 \}$ (we are claiming that only +1 is Positive , everything else is not)
Here , trichotomy holds.
More-over , Multiplicative Closure holds too : $(+1) \times (+1) = (+1)$
Additive Closure will not hold : $(+1) + (+1) = (+2)$
It will naturally break a lot of things , like we can not order all real numbers.
The moment we include Additive Closure , we say that $(+1)+(+1)=(+2)$ must be Positive & hence our $P$ is invalid.
That will ensure that $P$ must be what we commonly know.
Example 2 :
Consider this :
$P = \{ x | 0 \lt x \le +1 \}$
Here , trichotomy holds.
More-over , Multiplicative Closure holds too :
When $0 \lt x \lt +1$ & $0 \lt y \lt +1$ , we will have
$0 \lt xy \lt +1$
Additive Closure will not hold : $(+0.75) + (+0.39) = (+1.14)$
It too will naturally break a lot of things.
The moment we include Additive Closure , we say that$(+0.75) + (+0.39) = (+1.14)$ must be Positive & hence our $P$ is invalid.
That will ensure that $P$ must be what we commonly know.

I don't understand this answer. The question asks for a set $\Bbb P$ with these 4 properties: 1) closed by product; 2) not closed by addition; 3) does not contain $0$; 4) $[\forall x\in\Bbb R\setminus{0}, (x\in\Bbb P\Leftrightarrow -x\notin \Bbb P)]$. None of the sets you mention, be them $P$ or $D$, satisfy $(3)\land (4)$.

OP wants $P$ to be closed by multiplication & not by addition. When $P={+1}$ , it works out : (1) multiplication : yes (2) addition : no (3) Positive : yes (4) trichotomy : yes. Likewise for the other Example , @SassatelliGiulio , I just used $D$ to indicate the Degenerate real number system , with $P$ indicating the Positive number Subset there. I think what you are missing is that there is no $R$ yet , which is replaced by hypothetical $D$. We are trying to make $R$ which requires addition closure too. Without that , the $R$ we make will not be the regular $R$ , it will be Degenerate !

It seems to me that you're answering a simpler question of your own making, id est finding $\emptyset\subsetneq P\subseteq D\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $D$ is multiplicatively closed and $P$ satisfies $(1)\land (2)\land (3)$ and (5): $[\forall x\in D\setminus{0},(x\in P\leftrightarrow -x\notin P)]$. It's apparent that finding a pair such that $(1)\land (2)\land (3)\land (5)$ and $D\ne \Bbb R$ is rather easy.

Essentially , that was what OP is asking. It could alternately by taken that we already have made up the whole $R$ but we do not yet know the $P$. We generally use Multiplicative Closure , Additive closure & Trichotomy to make $P$. OP is asking whether we can make $P$ without Additive Closure , @SassatelliGiulio , I am saying that my $P$ Examples (where we either ignore or use $D$ according to what OP wants) show that Additive Closure is very much necessary to ensure that $P$ will indeed match the Expected Positives. These Degenerate $P$ Examples satisfy everything except Additive Closure.

I don't think you understood the question correctly. The question is asking for a set $P$ that has these properties with respect to the actual $\mathbb R$, not with respect to the hypothetical $D$.

I have removed $D$ which was unnecessary complication , @MishaLavrov , I think the rest of my answer giving $P$ Examples will stand.

Trichotomy does not hold for either of your examples of $P$, because for example we have neither $2 \in P$ nor $-2 \in P$.

Oh , nice , thank you for catching that. My $P$ uses modified $R$ , it will not work with regular $R$ , @MishaLavrov , So either there is no such CounterExample (OP is right with suspecting that Additive Closure is not necessary) or the CounterExample is going to be non-trivial.
